# Calling PresentViewController from a UISplitViewController causes exception

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

After updating to the newest Version of iOS Xamarin tools, whenever I call PresentViewController on my window.RootViewController, which is a UISplitViewController
I get the following exception:

```
[UISplitViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75f46d0
```

The strange thing is that the App was working OK before I updated the Xamarin stuff. 
I am currently using Xamarin Studio 4.0.12 and Xamarin iOS 6.4.3.0

Any Idea what the problem may be? 
Thanks

Comment: Could you share your code with me?

Comment: sorry I can't,  but after doing more testing I found out that the problem only occurs on older versions of iOS (4.3 and older). At this point we are probably just going to drop support for iOS older than 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

UISplitViewController doesn't respond to the selector
    presentViewController:animated:completion: 
You should call this on your DetailViewController.

Comment: I actually have two apps on the store and a test App that I wrote to try things out that work like this. My theory is that the new compiler is somehow initializing things differently. I may try what you suggest though and see if it works.

Comment: The UISplitViewController inherits from UIViewController and therefore can respond to presentViewController:animated:completion.